# Marionette - backbone how to use fetch correctly

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

This is a simple question but I can's see it answered in the Marionette Wiki.

If I load data into a Collection via a url what format does that data have to be in?

Does it have to have an ID like this:

```
[
  {id: "something", name: "Justin", hobbies: ""},
  {id: "something2", name: "Fred", hobbies: ""}  
]
```

Is the ID field required for it to work properly?

Comment: Also, your id field doesn't have to be called "id". You can set what it is call in the idAttribute in your model definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should have an `id` attribute: Backbone determines whether the model instance has been persisted on the remote server by checking whether it has an `id` value or not.

- if it has an id => use HTTP `PUT` verb to cause an update
- if it doesn't have an id => use HTTP `POST` verb to create a new record

Comment: So. when I so model.save if it has no ID backbone will automatically to a POST?  (According to the other answer I can pass http verb as an option to save, which is fine, but I was just looking at the default behaviour).

Comment: Yes, by default, Backbone will assume you're creating a new model instance, which will result in a POST

Answer (score 0):

We do not use id field in our data set so it is not a 'must'. We also manage when to use POST or PUT directly from the client code and not relying on backbone to do it automatically.

```
model.save(..., {type: 'POST'});
model.save(..., {type: 'PUT'});
```